# KnockoutJS - foreach not working with a single entry in viewmodel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have the following code that, on a successful AJAX return, displays a popup window with a list of addresses.  The knockout version is 2.3.0.

If there is more than 1 address then the html correctly renders with a 'display' string.

The problem is that if there is ONLY 1 address the html list renders but without any text in the span.

In both cases the view model is correctly being populated with data so it looks to me like a problem updating the html.

I have tried pushing the data again and although I can use jQuery to update the html but this doesn't help me understand the problem.

HTML

```
    <div id="reverseGeocodingResults">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Local Addresses</h4>
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul data-bind="foreach: vm.reverseGeocodingViewModel.AddressList" class="locationList">
                    <li class="locationListItem" data-bind="click: SubmitAddressRequest">
                        <div>
                            <span data-bind="text: Display"></span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript (from a separate file so only taken what I think is relevant)

```
    var vm;
    var masterViewModel = function () {
        this.viewModel = { LocationList: ko.observableArray([]), SubQuery: ko.observable() };
        this.reverseGeocodingViewModel = { AddressList: ko.observableArray([]) };
    };

    function SubmitReverseGeocodingRequest(easting, northing, projectId, mouseLocation) {
        $.post('url?action=ReverseGeocodingLookup', {
            easting: easting,
            northing: northing,
            pid: projectId
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            spinner.stop();
            if (parseInt(data.NumberOfAddressesFound) > 0) {
                if (data.AddressList.length == 1) {
                    alert('just 1 address');
                }

                // remove all array items before adding new
                // Not pretty but gets around an issue the UI seems to have displaying the updated list
                if (vm.reverseGeocodingViewModel.AddressList().length > 0) {
                    vm.reverseGeocodingViewModel.AddressList.splice(0, vm.reverseGeocodingViewModel.AddressList().length);
                }

                vm.reverseGeocodingViewModel.AddressList(data.AddressList);
            }
        });
    )

    $(document).ready(function () {
        vm = new masterViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
    })
```

HTML Result - Multiple Results

```
    <ul class="locationList" data-bind="foreach: vm.reverseGeocodingViewModel.AddressList" style="height: 265px;">
        <li data-bind="click: SubmitAddressRequest" class="locationListItem">
            <div>
                <span data-bind="text: Display">Yates Wine Lodge, SWINDON</span>
            </div>
        </li>                        
        <li data-bind="click: SubmitAddressRequest" class="locationListItem">
            <div>
                <span data-bind="text: Display">The Brunel Centre, SWINDON</span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

HTML Result - Single Result

```
    <ul class="locationList" data-bind="foreach: vm.reverseGeocodingViewModel.AddressList" style="height: 265px;">
        <li class="locationListItem" data-bind="click: SubmitAddressRequest">
            <div>
                <span data-bind="text: Display"></span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I have looked at various previous questions on this topic and couldn't come up with an answer hence the question, but please point me to another post if I have missed one.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `splice` code. If your binding is having issues displaying the list if you don't `splice` first it would seem as though you have other issues with your code. Also, your viewmodel does not really seem to be encapsulating all it should, but that's another discussion. However, back to your specific issue, I'm not sure it is possible to help you with only the information you have provided. Could you please create a [minimal, complete and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example and preferably also that example running on a site like jsfiddle/jsbin/plunker?

Answer (score 0):

1. to remove all before add new use `reverseGeocodingViewModel.AddressList.removeAll()`
2. Maybe didn't find it but you have to parse data, `$.parseJSON` I use for this.
3. Try to use

   `$.each($.parsejSON(data), function(i, el){
     reverseGeocodingViewModel.AddressList.push(el);
   })`

I hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed following issues:

- function `SubmitReverseGeocodingRequest` should be closed with `}` not `)`
- `foreach: vm.reverseGeocodingViewModel.AddressList` should be `foreach: reverseGeocodingViewModel.AddressList`, without `vm` because `vm` is already binded

  `vm = new masterViewModel();
   ko.applyBindings(vm);`
- To clean `AddressList` use `vm.reverseGeocodingViewModel.AddressList([])` instead `vm.reverseGeocodingViewModel.AddressList.splice(0, vm.reverseGeocodingViewModel.AddressList().length);`

Note: Here's possible mistake

```
<li class="locationListItem" data-bind="click: SubmitAddressRequest">
```

so `AddressList` item have to have the `SubmitAddressRequest` function. I don't think that you get data with the function

I've created test sample based on your code, take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HD8tu/5/)